# Code P0421 Mitusubishi Outlander/Temperature gauge goes up

Tags: overheating, mitsubishi

Temperature gauge goes up when I have AC on. Also I notice that it goes up when I go uphill. The mechanic changed the thermostat and temperature gauge seemed to work good for about 2 weeks. After 2 weeks, The "check engine" light came on again. The temperature gauge start going up again as before. Now I'm driving without A.C. and I set  the temperature gauge to max heat without turning it on and the temperature gauge behaves ok. Can you please help? Thank you very much!

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the year of the manufacture? Is this the plug-in hybrid electric vehicle or traditional internal combustion engine? I considered the PHEV, but went for Toyota RAV4 hybrid instead that cannot be charged externally. The apartment building owner company probably likes my decision as I don't consume excessive amounts of electricity now.